# Rcpp modules: Returning a reference to a member variable c++ object to R

Tags: rcpp

I have a C++ class that stores a raw pointer to an objects of its own kind as a member variable. The class is exposed via Rcpp modules to R. I would like to return a reference to the member variable via a property. However, it seems that a copy is returned.

This also applies to other cases where different member variable objects are returned to R.

**Minimal reproducible example**

I create a new skeleton package using `Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton('testmod', module = TRUE)` and added my own class `Foo`, exposing it to R. The example can be found [here](https://github.com/DominikMueller64/testmod.git) on github.

Content of src/Foo.cpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

class Foo;
RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Foo)

class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo():
      ancestor_ptr(NULL){}
    Foo(const Foo& ancestor):
      ancestor_ptr(&ancestor){}

    const Foo& get_ancestor() {return *ancestor_ptr;}

    const Foo* ancestor_ptr;
};


RCPP_MODULE(mymodule){
  using namespace Rcpp ;

  class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .default_constructor()
    .constructor<const Foo&>()
    .property("ancestor", &Foo::get_ancestor)
    ;
}
```

Testing in an R session gives me:

```
>library(testmod)
>a <- new(Foo)
>b <- new(Foo, a)
>a
C++ object <0x1c57108> of class 'Foo' <0x22d78b0>
>b$ancestor
C++ object <0x1f8ffa0> of class 'Foo' <0x22d78b0>
```

So `0x1c57108 != 0x1f8ffa0`, and I checked with helper functions not shown that 0x1c57108 is actually the address of object `a`.

**EDIT**
I just checked with the help of a uuid member variable and a custom copy constructor that actually copies of the member objects are being made.

Comment: I am not sure I am making the same assumption as you that this should work.  Simpler approach may be a first C++ class with pointers to other instances.  You manage that memory yourself, which is just a plain C++ application.  Then you use one Rcpp Module-based class to access this new structure.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel So you mean that this might not be possible at all? I'm wondering at which place a copy is made. With your suggestion, you mean to use kind of a controller class that functions as a handle to manage the whole application from R? However, returning references would be really a good thing as it allows implementing/prototyping some features in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that modules can't really handle returning references, so when calling `get_ancestor` a copy is being made.

Consider this expanded version of your code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

class Foo;
RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(Foo)

  class Foo
  {
  public:
    Foo():
    ancestor_ptr(NULL){}
    Foo(const Foo& ancestor):
      ancestor_ptr(&ancestor)
    {
      Rprintf( "Foo(const Foo&)\n")  ;  
    }

    const Foo& get_ancestor() {return *ancestor_ptr;}
    const Foo* ancestor_ptr;

    void print_ptr(){
      Rprintf( "ptr = %p\n", this ) ;
    }

    void print_ancestor_ptr(){
      Rprintf( "ptr = %p\n", ancestor_ptr ) ;
    }

  };


RCPP_MODULE(mymodule){
  using namespace Rcpp ;

  class_<Foo>("Foo")
    .default_constructor()
    .constructor<const Foo&>()
    .property("ancestor", &Foo::get_ancestor)
    .method( "print_ptr", &Foo::print_ptr )
    .method( "print_ancestor_ptr", &Foo::print_ancestor_ptr )
  ;
}
```

A copy is made when you invoke the copy constructor, which is fine and what you mean to happen:

```
> a  <- new( Foo )
> b <- new( Foo, a )
Foo(const Foo&)
```

But one is also made when you call `get_ancestor` :

```
> b$ancestor
Foo(const Foo&)
C++ object <0x10204ee00> of class 'Foo' <0x10207c7c0>
```

However, in `b` you indeed store the correct pointer:

```
> a$print_ptr()
ptr = 0x113278820
> b$print_ancestor_ptr() 
ptr = 0x113278820
```

Comment: Thank's for your clear answer! Seems that there is no other way than redesigning my application to run exclusively on the C++ side.

Comment: Indeed, short of reworking modules so that they would properly handle references. `Boost.Python` does it so it's possible.

Comment: It would be totally awesome. Is there any realistic expectation that this feature will be added in near future?

Comment: I would not bet on it.